# How can I add a timeout to a dart stream

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to get a timeout when I listen to a stream but don't receive a value after a duration.
Here is a example how it could look like:

```
dtcStatus.valueStream.stream.listen
   ((event) {
         do Something with the event
   }, 
   timeoutDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), 
   onTimeout: () {
    do something on the timeout here
   }
);
```

could that be archived with an extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method on Stream:

```
timeout(Duration timeLimit, {void onTimeout(EventSink<T> sink)}) → Stream<T>
Creates a new stream with the same events as this stream. [...]
```

should be exactly what you want.  You even had the syntax nearly right!

Comment: yeah thanks just found it as well...
dtcStatus.valueStream.stream.timeout( Duration(milliseconds: 300),onTimeout: (_){}).listen((event) {}

Comment: for quick reference, here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/timeout.html